# Delphi 7, Titan BTrieve Components

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, btrieve

I am using Delphi 7, and Titan BTrieve to open a Pervasive Table.

It is a TtbTable component.

I am trying to apply the filter on a TimeStamp field with my code as follows:

```
    Date:=InputDate;
    DateString:=FormatDateTime('DD/MM/YYYY HH:NN:SS', InputDate);
    Table1.Filter:='UPDATEDON > '+chr(39)+DAteString+chr(39);
    Table1.Filtered:=True;
```

The problem is that the filter results are incorrect.  It returns records that are before the do not match the filter criteria.

Comment: Did you contact the vendor yet?

Comment: They no longer exist or support the product.  I bought the components from from Regatta software and they are not interested.

Comment: shouldn't the date format be YEAR.MONTH.DAY HOUR:MINUTE:SECOND.MILISECOND?

Answer (score 1):

the Table1.Filter, filters the data in TDataSet not in btrieve/pervasive.

the problem is the date in string format... you must use the formar YYYY-MM-DD and not DD-MM-YYYY because the string compare.

in a string compare 17-06-2012 is grater than 16-07-2012, (17>16)

Answer (score 0):

From the look of it, you are comparing strings, not dates.

Comment: I am comparing dates, but to build a filter the date parameters need to be converted and passed as string.  This is the way of it with TTable filter.  This component is inherited from ttable.

Answer (score 0):

What version of PSQL are you using?  Is the UPDATEDON field defined as a Timestamp in the Btrieve database?  If it's a timestamp, values are stored in 8-byte unsigned values representing septaseconds (10^-7 second) since January 1, 0001 in a Gregorian calendar, Coordinated Universal Time (UTC). It is not stored as a string.

Btrieve / PSQL stores dates in the 'YYYY-MM-DD' format.

WHat does a value from the UPDATEDON field look like?  To use it as a filter, you need to make sure the filter value looks the same.

Comment: Thank you I checked all of this and nothing seems to be working.  Pervasive has formatting checks and my filter parameters pass these checks.  They must have a bug in their component.  My formatting was spot on I have tested it now in DBISAM and DBASE and PARADOX and it worked perfectly.  Just with pervasive now I am having a problem and it must be the component that is buggy.  Thank you.

Comment: You may be able to find what the error situation is (and work around it) by supplying ever more complex datetime strings. Start with '1-1-1' and '1/1/1', then try '15/5/1' and '5/15/01' etc.

Comment: @Nico, If you use the PCC (or ODBC Test)and read the UPDATEDON field, what does a value look like?  Does the standard TTable component work?  What about PDAC (Pervasive's VCL control)?